# Django Unique Together (with foreign keys)

Tags: python, django, django-models, indexing, unique-constraint

I have a situation where I want to use the Meta options of `unique_together` to enforce a certain rule, here's the intermediary model:

```py
class UserProfileExtension(models.Model):
    extension = models.ForeignKey(Extension, unique=False)
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, unique=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)  

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("userprofile", "extension"),
                           ("user", "extension"),
                           # How can I enforce UserProfile's Client 
                           # and Extension to be unique? This obviously
                           # doesn't work, but is this idea possible without
                           # creating another FK in my intermediary model 
                           ("userprofile__client", "extension"))
```

and here's UserProfile:

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can't.

The `unique_together` clause is directly translated to the `SQL` unique index. And you can only set those on columns of a single table, not a combination of several tables.

You can add validation for it yourself though, simply overwrite the `validate_unique` method and add this validation to it.

Docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was searching for.
Answer below by @Manu is also helpful.

Answer (score 18):

My 2 cents, *complementing* the accepted response from @Wolph

> You can add validation for it yourself though, simply overwrite the validate_unique method and add this validation to it.

This is a working example code someone could find usefull.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class MyModel(models.Model):

    fk = models.ForeignKey(AnotherModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    my_field = models.CharField(...)  # whatever

    def validate_unique(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().validate_unique(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.__class__.objects.\
                filter(fk=self.fk, my_field=self.my_field).\
                exists():
            raise ValidationError(
                message='MyModel with this (fk, my_field) already exists.',
                code='unique_together',
            )
```

Comment: This will not pass when editing a MyModel instance that exists already.

Comment: should work for an already existing model, what's the error you're getting?

Comment: Not an error, the queryset will return the loaded object also, therefor it will always raise the duplicate error of itself, you should exclude the object id from the queryset.

Answer (score 13):

My solution was to use Django's [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create-kwargs).  By using get_or_create, a useless get will occur if the row already exists in the database, and the row will be created if it does not exist.

**Example:**

```
 
extension = Extension.objects.get(pk=someExtensionPK)

userProfile = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=someUserProfilePK)

UserProfileExtension.objects.get_or_create(extension=extension, userprofile=userProfile)
```

Comment: Just be careful. This can fail if you are using transactions (which you probably are).

Answer (score 5):

From django 2.2+ versions, it is suggested to use constraint & Index as model class meta option:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.unique_together

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.constraints

```
class UniqueConstraintModel(models.Model):
    race_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = models.IntegerField()
    global_id = models.IntegerField()
    fancy_conditions = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                name="unique_constraint_model_global_id_uniq",
                fields=('global_id',),
            ),
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                name="unique_constraint_model_fancy_1_uniq",
                fields=('fancy_conditions',),
                condition=models.Q(global_id__lte=1)
            ),
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                name="unique_constraint_model_fancy_3_uniq",
                fields=('fancy_conditions',),
                condition=models.Q(global_id__gte=3)
            ),
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                name="unique_constraint_model_together_uniq",
                fields=('race_name', 'position'),
                condition=models.Q(race_name='example'),
            )
        ]
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to call [Models.full_clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) method to call validate_unique for foreignKey. You can override save() to call this

```
class UserProfileExtension(models.Model):
    extension = models.ForeignKey(Extension, unique=False)
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, unique=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)  


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("userprofile", "extension"),
                       ("user", "extension"),
                       # How can I enforce UserProfile's Client 
                       # and Extension to be unique? This obviously
                       # doesn't work, but is this idea possible without
                       # creating another FK in my intermediary model 
                       ("userprofile__client", "extension"))
```

Comment: This works great.  Actually, as of Django 5.0 (only tested on this), you don't even need to override save().  Just Meta with unique_together works.

Comment: Does not work for me: I get the error "'unique_together' refers to the nonexistent field 'userprofile__client'." 
Django 5.0, Python 3.11.4

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

.....

class UserProfileExtension(models.Model):
    extension = models.ForeignKey(Extension, unique=False)
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, unique=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)  

    def validate_unique(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileExtension, self).validate_unique(*args, **kwargs)
        query = UserProfileExtension.objects.filter(extension=self.extension)
        if query.filter(userprofile__client=self.userprofile.client).exists():
            raise ValidationError({'extension':['Extension already exits for userprofile__client',]})
```

The first query is to filter all records in UserProfileExtension model which has the same extension we are putting in the current record.

Then we filter the query returned to find if it already contains userprofile__client which we are passing in the current record.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to add this on your save method from your Model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    unique = self.__class__.objects.filter( extension =self.extension, userprofile=self.userprofile )
    if unique.exists():
        self.id = unique[0].id
    super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```