# django calls validate_unique twice - workaround?

Tags: django, django-models

I understand `validate_unique` is only called when doing a `full_clean`, which is in turn only called when calling `ModelForm.save()` - so that means `validate_unique` won't automatically be called when doing a `model_instance.save()`

eg. see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14472335/996792

I *do* want to call `validate_unique` when calling `model_instance.save` so I've overridden my model's `save` function as follows:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.validate_unique()
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, this produces the following quirk: now when saving from a `ModelForm` (eg. in the admin), `validate_unique` is called twice! Presumably once for the `ModelForm.save()` and once for the `Model.save()`.

Is there anyway round this inefficiency?

I detest unnecessary cruft and this sort of thing bothers me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible workaround:

`clean(` method is called when request comes from a modelform, set a flag when this method is called:

```
def clean( self ):
    self.clean_called = True   #<---- this is the flag.
    #other model checks
```

Overwrite `save(` i order to call `validate_unique` only if flag is not set. Don't forget to remove flag.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    flag_is_set = hasattr( self, 'clean_called' ) and self.clean_called
    if not flag_is_set:
        self.validate_unique()
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.clean_called = False
```