# Proper way of adding Custom Django Model Validation

Tags: python, django

As I was searching the ways of adding the model validation I found more than one way to achieve it. For eg if my model is as follows:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class ChatThread(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to validate such that user1 & user2 are different.
Then I could have following options:

- override the `save` method
- implement `clean` or `full_clean` method
- use `signals` `pre_save`
- ...

What would be the best approach for these kind of task ??

Comment: For this simple validation, I would use the `unique_together` attribute of the `Meta` class of your `ChatThread` model.

Comment: thanks @May.D, `unique_together` attribute would be suitable here

Comment: @May.D adding a unique constraint is probably a good idea, however it doesn't solve the validation requirement in question.  For example, inserting `ChatThread(user1_id=1, user2_id=1)` would pass the unique constraint, but result in identical users in the same instance.

Comment: Indeed you are right, in fact I just tested it and `unique_together` doesnt work for foreign keys, as explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38081616/8237838 (see also comments). My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add a database level *check constraint* to your model, which can be done with the following:

```
from django.db.models import Q, F

class ChatThread(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(check=(
                ~Q(user1=F('user2'))
            ), name='check_users_not_equal')
        ]
```

The line `Q(user1=F('user2'))` checks that the `user1` field is equal to the `user2` field, and the tilde `~`, checks that the preceding `Q` object **is not** true.

> Is a database level check constraint better/more effective than the conventional methods shown above?

The general argument in favor of application-level validation is the **[DRY Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)**.  For example, if you have a model with an email field, and a database-level constraint verifying that the input is a valid email, you would end up writing the validation logic twice; once for the database-constraint, and once in the client-side code.  You could forgo the client-side validation, but that would result in your users receiving generic error messages anytime they enter an invalid email.

In your specific case, I would strongly recommend database-level validation over application-level validation.  If a piece of logic violates this rule (ie. `user1 != user2`), then it is almost guaranteed to be the result of broken code, and not user-input, which means the end user will receive a generic error message in either case.

There are more pros and cons to each approach that I didn't mention.  If you want to read more on this topic, I'd start here: [Should you enforce constraints at the database level as well as the application level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464042/should-you-enforce-constraints-at-the-database-level-as-well-as-the-application)

Comment: Thanks for showing this approach. Is database level check constraint is better/effective than the conventional methods shown above??

Comment: @AbishekBashyal good question!  See my update on why I'd prefer a constraint in this case.

Comment: ok thnx!... really appreciate for your time.