# Can I use the field of a related model in a Django UniqueConstraint?

Tags: django, django-models, unique-constraint

Is it possible to make a `UniqueConstraint` using the field of a foreignkey model?

For example, how could I constrain all books written by authors of the same age to have a unique title?  (*A contrived example, but you get the idea.*)

**models.py**:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Book(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        contraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                # THIS DOESN'T WORK
                fields=["author__age", "title"],
                name="my_constraint",
            )
        ]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="books")
```

This gives the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Book has no field named 'author__age

'

Answer (score 4):

No, `UniqueConstraint` doesn't work like that yet. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470585/how-to-validate-uniqueness-constraint-across-foreign-key-django) for possible alternatives.

Comment: Thank you.  That helps.  In my real code, `author.age` is actually another foreignkey, so I just setup a `UniqueConstraint` on that model.