# django multiple models with same foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals, django-constraints

I have django app that is tracking contracts, locations, and products for various clients. Contracts, Locations each reference the client with a ForeignKey.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Contract(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

I also have a product that will be deployed in a location, on a contract, for a client.  I need to include client in product because the reference is used to secure the record to that client.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ....
```

What is the best way to make sure a product is never created that contains a different client reference across all 3 models?  I was thinking I could use a pre_save signal but I would rather use a database constraint but I don't see a database constraint to force this.

Comment: this looks like bad modeling, why all of these models have client if client must be same

Comment: @iklinac we need to be able to enter a location that is tied to a client. we also need to enter a contract that is tied to a client. these objects are not related.  i could remove the client reference from product but I would still have the same problem.  how would you suggest I model this?

Comment: aha, it looks like multitenant arhitecture on same database then, do clients write their own locations etc as you can always limit set to current client  by overriding default manager

Comment: @iklinac this is multi-tenant.  clients can write their own data... we have agents that can write to a subset of client records and we have agents that can write to all the client records.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into the [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together). I think this will do what you want to do.

Also keep the following in mind.

> UniqueConstraint provides more functionality than unique_together. unique_together may be deprecated in the future.

Comment: unique_together makes sure different fields are unique in a table to avoid duplicate conflicting records.  I would like to make sure they are all referencing the same record.

Comment: So basically, what you want is that Contract and Location are also linked to the same client in the Product. If I understand correctly.

Comment: I am afraid you cannot do that at the database level. Instead either update your model save method and add the functionality programatically. As you mentioned `pre_save` is a good option. But if you don't wanna go towards the db signals then this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/14471010/5084737

Comment: thanks.  this is basically what I am doing currently.  I am throwing an integrity error in an overridden save method.  However, I noticed that with the constraints django actually returns the user to the input page with a note so it is easy to update.  When I manually throw the integrity error (or validationerror) it just stops and displays an error page.  maybe I should just be trying to figure out how to make the error return the user to the input page.