# Django Rest Framework IntegrityError when tried use unique_together

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201598/how-to-define-two-fields-unique-as-couple) seems to be similar to what I am aiming for but I get an error

```
IntegrityError column username_id is not unique
```

What I am looking for is having these fields be unique only when together. Meaning that the same `roomId` and username can only be seen in the database once when together.
 However, a user can be seen with another `roomId`. The point is to avoid multiple submissions of the same user and the same `roomId`. 
The error above occurs when I try to submit another requst with the same username to another `roomId`.

Here is my model

```
class Active(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    roomId = models.ForeignKey(Room)
    activeId = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
                            editable=False)
    class Meta:
        unique_together=(('username', 'roomId',))
```

I am using `SQLite` and.

I thought the unique_together constraint did this but it doesn't seem like it. What's the proper approach?

**Edit**

I ended up overriding the perform_create and verify that no row contains both keys before saving like in this [link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview).

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    queryset = Active.objects.filter(username=serializer.data.get('username')).filter(roomId=serializer.data.get('roomId'))
    if queryset.exists():
        raise ValidationError({"detail" : "dont be silly"})
    serializer.save()
```

Seems to be working fine.

Regards

Comment: you will have to override the create method either on the viewset or on the serializer that you are using. :)

Comment: could you explain why taking this approach and what is the purpose of unique_together as an answer?

Comment: Do you have some signals set up ?

Comment: I do not. Check out the edit

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, was already answered: [Django Unique Together (with foreign keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440010/django-unique-together-with-foreign-keys)

What you are looking for might be already provided by the many to many relation. Can you use that relation on user or room instead ?

Comment: I think I could. I ended up overwriting the perfrom_create(self, serializer) on my view instead. Executed to filters on it and check if it exists. I do wonder the performance of that method as the DB gets large.

Comment: There will be a performance impact but I would say it's negligible - it happens only at object creation. Another way to approach this is to write a custom object manager where you overwrite the create method. This way you are hardening the condition as close to the dB layer as possible, making such a validation available for admin site as well.