# Django: unique_together for foreign field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

For next two models:

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    name = models.CharField()


class Bar(models.Model):
    foreign = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I need to have unique_together constraint for `Bar` model:

```py
class Meta:
    unique_together = ('value', 'foreign__parent')
```

Which is impossible in Django.

But is it possible to achieve this on database level (Postgresql) with some contraint or model level validation to omit possible case (lock table?) when simultaneously same `value` may be saved to different `Bar` instances?

**Django 2.2.4**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440010/django-unique-together-with-foreign-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Anjaneyulu Batta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4859910/anjaneyulu-batta), came to next solution:

```py
@contextmanager
def lock_table(model):
    """
    Lock target table on commands UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT
    """
    with transaction.atomic(), transaction.get_connection().cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            f'LOCK TABLE {model._meta.db_table} IN ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;'
        )
        yield
```

And for model:

```py
def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
    super().validate_unique(exclude)
    queryset = type(self).objects.filter(
        value=self.value,
        foreign__parent=self.foreign.parent,
    )

    if self.pk:
        queryset = queryset.exclude(pk=self.pk)

    if queryset.exists():
        raise IntegrityError(_('Value must be unique for foreign field'))

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):
    with lock_table(type(self)):
        self.validate_unique()
        super().save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

Should work fairly save.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve it with `unique_together` because it creates an index in the database level. But, You can add validation for it yourself though, simply overwrite the `validate_unique` method and add this validation to it.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Bar(models.Model):
    foreign = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def validate_unique(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).validate_unique(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.__class__.objects.\
                filter(foreign__parent=self.foreign.parent, vaue=self.value).exists():
            raise ValidationError(
                message='record already exists with given values.',
                code='unique_together',
            )
```

Comment: @Sibirsky I guess it should call `validate_unique` when `is_valid()` method invoked on `serializer`.

Comment: feels like it doesn't.

Comment: did you test it ?

Comment: Yes, got bunch of unit tests. I can add appropriate validations to serializer, but what about model level? I mean, if I just add `validate_unique()` to `Bar`, it won't trigger by itself if I try to save model - I would need to add this inside of `save()` at least, but that's also not good since I got lots of validations on serializer itself.

Comment: It should also work with it. did you try checking it with model `save` method ?

Comment: Yes. `Model.save()` doesn't trigger `validate_unique()`.

Comment: You can override save method and use `Model.full_clean`  method inside it. Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/db/models/base/#Model.full_clean