# Is there a way to create a unique id over 2 fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is my model:

```
class GroupedModels(models.Model):
    other_model_one = models.ForeignKey('app.other_model')
    other_model_two = models.ForeignKey('app.other_model')
```

Essentially, what I want is is for `other_model` to be unique in this table.  That means that if there is a record where `other_model_one` id is `123`, I should not allow another record to be created with `other_model_two` id as `123`.  I can override `clean` I guess but I was wondering if django has something built in.

I am using version 2.2.5 with PSQL.

Edit: This is not a unqiue together situation.  If I add a record with `other_model_one_id=1` and other `other_model_two_id=2`, I should not be able to add another record with `other_model_one_id=2` and other `other_model_two_id=1`

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.2.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Unique Together (with foreign keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440010/django-unique-together-with-foreign-keys)

Comment: This is not a unique together situation, this is unique but over 2 fields if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I explain several options here, maybe one of them or a combination can be useful for you.

#### Overriding `save`

Your constraint is a business rule, you can override `save` method to keep data consistent:

```py
class GroupedModels(models.Model): 
    # ...
    def clean(self):
        if (self.other_model_one.pk == self.other_model_two.pk):
            raise ValidationError({'other_model_one':'Some message'}) 
        if (self.other_model_one.pk < self.other_model_two.pk):
            #switching models
            self.other_model_one, self.other_model_two = self.other_model_two, self.other_model_one
    # ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.clean()
        super(GroupedModels, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

#### Change design

I put a sample easy to understand. Let's suppose this scenario:

```py
class BasketballMatch(models.Model):
    local = models.ForeignKey('app.team')
    visitor = models.ForeignKey('app.team')
```

Now, you want to avoid a team playing a match with itself also team A only can play with team B for once (almost your rules). You can redesign your models as:

```py
class BasketballMatch(models.Model):
    HOME = 'H'
    GUEST = 'G'
    ROLES = [
        (HOME, 'Home'),
        (GUEST, 'Guest'),
    ]
    match_id = models.IntegerField()
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ROLES)
    player = models.ForeignKey('app.other_model')

    class Meta:
      unique_together = [ ( 'match_id', 'role', ) ,
                          ( 'match_id', 'player',) , ]
```

#### `ManyToManyField.symmetrical`

This look like a [symetrical](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) issue, django can handle it for you. Instead of create `GroupedModels` model, just make a ManyToManyField field with itself on `OtherModel`:

```py
from django.db import models
class OtherModel(models.Model):
    ...
    grouped_models = models.ManyToManyField("self")
```

This is what django has as built in for these scenarios.

Comment: Approach one is the one I was using (but hoping for a database constraint).  Approach 2 is a little different in that in my scenario, if a team has played a game, they can never play a game again.  I didn't use approach 3 because there was more data I wanted to store on the the grouping.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: _if a team has played a game, they can never play a game again._ because this I included `match_id` on unike constraint, to allow teams to play unlimited matchs. Just remove this field to restrict play again.

Comment: ah yes! thank you I missed that and my other model could be a one to one field.

Comment: I think I like option number 2 best.  The only issue I have with it is that it arguably needs a custom form for the "average" user, in a world where the admin is used as the FE.  Unfortunately, I live in that world.  But I think this should be the accepted answer.  Thanks!

Comment: The second option is the way to go. This is a great answer. @Pitfall regarding the admin I have added a further answer. The admin form shouldn't be a big problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a very satisfying answer, but unfortunately the truth is there is no way to do what you're describing with a simple built-in feature.

What you described with `clean` would work, but you have to be careful to manually call it as I think it's only automatically called when using ModelForm.  You might be able to [create a complex database constraint](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47840/complex-constraint-across-all-data-in-a-table) but that would live outside of Django and you'd have to handle database exceptions (which can be difficult in Django when in the middle of a transaction).

Maybe there's a better way to structure the data?

Comment: Yes, you are correct that it has to be manually called which is why I didn't like the approach.  It only works as I want in the admin, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58614958/3848833) from **[dani herrera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/842935/dani-herrera)**, however I wish to further elaborate on it.

As explained in the second option, the solution as required by the OP is to change the design and implement two unique constraints pairwise. The analogy with the basketball matches illustrates the problem in a very practical way.

Instead of a basketball match, I use example with football (or soccer) games. A football game (which I call it `Event`) is played by two teams (in my models a team is `Competitor`). This is a many-to-many relation (`m:n`), with `n` limited to two in this particular case, the principle is suitable for an unlimited number.

Here is how our models look:

```
class Competitor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(Competitor)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

An event could be:

- title: Carabao Cup, 4th round,
- venue: Anfield
- time: 30. October 2019, 19:30 GMT
- participants:

  - name: Liverpool, city: Liverpool
  - name: Arsenal, city: London

Now we have to solve the issue from the question. Django automatically creates an intermediate table between the models with a many-to-many relation, but we can use a custom model and add further fields. I call that model `Participant`:

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    ROLES = (
        ('H', 'Home'),
        ('V', 'Visitor'),
    )
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    competitor = models.ForeignKey(Competitor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ROLES)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('event', 'role'),
            ('event', 'competitor'),
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.event, self.get_role_display())
```

The `ManyToManyField` has an option `through` that allows us to specify the intermediate model. Let's change that in the model `Event`:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(
        Competitor,
        related_name='events', # if we want to retrieve events for a competitor
        through='Participant'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The unique constraints now will automatically limit the number of competitors per event to two (because there are only two roles: **Home** and **Visitor**).

In a particular event (football game) there can be only one home team and only one visitor team. A club (`Competitor`) can appear either as home team or as visitor team.

How do we manage now all these things in the admin? Like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Competitor, Event, Participant


class ParticipantInline(admin.StackedInline): # or admin.TabularInline
    model = Participant
    max_num = 2


class CompetitorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name', 'city',)


class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('title', 'venue', 'time',)
    inlines = [ParticipantInline]


admin.site.register(Competitor, CompetitorAdmin)
admin.site.register(Event, EventAdmin)
```

We have added the `Participant` as inline in the `EventAdmin`. When we create new `Event` we can choose the home team and the visitor team. The option `max_num` limits the number of entries to 2, therefore no more then 2 teams can be added per event.

This can be refactored for a different use cases. Let's say our events are swimming competitions and instead of home and visitor, we have lanes 1 to 8. We just refactor the `Participant`:

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    ROLES = (
        ('L1', 'lane 1'),
        ('L2', 'lane 2'),
        # ... L3 to L8
    )
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    competitor = models.ForeignKey(Competitor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ROLES)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('event', 'role'),
            ('event', 'competitor'),
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.event, self.get_role_display())
```

With this modification we can have this event:

- title: FINA 2019, 50m backstroke men's final,

  - venue: Nambu University Municipal Aquatics Center
  - time: 28. July 2019, 20:02 UTC+9
  - participants:

    - name: Michael Andrew, city: Edina, USA, role: lane 1
    - name: Zane Waddell, city: Bloemfontein, South Africa, role: lane 2
    - name: Evgeny Rylov, city: Novotroitsk, Russia, role: lane 3
    - name: Kliment Kolesnikov, city: Moscow, Russia, role: lane 4

    // and so on lane 5 to lane 8 (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swimming_at_the_2019_World_Aquatics_Championships_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_50_metre_backstroke)

A swimmer can appear only once in a heat, and a lane can be occupied only once in a heat.

I put the code to GitHub: https://github.com/cezar77/competition.

Again, all credits go to dani herrera. I hope this answer provides some added value to the readers.