# Django: Model UniqueConstraint gives an error when migrating

Tags: python, django, django-models, unique-constraint

In my Django project the in one of the model I need to use two UniqueConstraint instances. But when I add that and do the migration after running makemigrations it gives an error in the terminal.

Model class:

```
class MyDays(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "My Day"
        verbose_name_plural = "My Days"
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['userid', 'date', 'from'], condition=Q(status=1), name='user_date_from_a'),
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['userid', 'date', 'to'], condition=Q(status=1), name='user_date_to_b')
        ]

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="User")
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, editable=True, validators=[validate_date])
    from = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, editable=True)
    to = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, editable=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Status", default=1)
```

When I run python3 manage.py migrate, it gives the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Joined field references are not
>   permitted in this query

I need to have unique records only if the status is 1 along with the other 3 field combination. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you show the full traceback? Are you sure the error is about *this* `UniqueConstraint`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  Yes. It appears with it. When I revert the model back to where it had only unique_together and removing the newly generated migration files it works fine. When I add these UniqueConstraint I get this error.

Comment: this might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440010/django-unique-together-with-foreign-keys

Answer (score 0):

Try `fields=['userid_id'...`

It looks like the `UniqueConstraint`s are trying to join across to the user table.

Django takes your ForeignKeys and OneToOneFields and adds `_id` to the end to create the DB column storing the related object's primary key (usually an integer). You generally shouldn't put "id" on the end of related object names for that reason.

So if `my_days` is an instance of `MyDays`, then `my_days.userid` is a user instance and `my_days.userid_id` is (usually) an integer.

If the behaviour is different with `unique_together`, that might be considered a bug in `UniqueConstraint`.